# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS partition not visible

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ubuntu-one, boot-partition, disk-management

I installed the ubuntu 20.04 lts alongside the windows boot manager going through the easy setup and didn't select the 'something else' option.
I didn't create a partition beforehand.The setup prompted me to resize my disk and make a partition with a graphical slider in the installer. But it comes out that I can't see the 90GB partition which I created. My disk management in windows doesn't show up any new partitions and my windows drives in 'this pc' are as the were before. Please help. What do I do if I need to remove the ubuntu in future?

Comment: Did your 20.04 install successfully? Does it boot? Is the space available in your Windows partition the older/larger size or the newer/smaller size?

Comment: @user535733 yes everything is working as it should. And space available is also the same as it was before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 2):

1- Windows is not able to see Gnu/Linux partitions.

2- Never, but never remove the installation of a Gnu/Linux system, deleting its partitions will leave the system unusable.

3- To remove Ubuntu, look for a guide on this site.

Comment: Thanks, but I got my way out :) Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorted it out!**

1. Boot from the live USB which you used to install ubuntu.
2. Use fdisk /dev/sda (your hard disk) to list all the partitions and enter the fdisk command mode. Refer https://wiki.mageia.org/en/How_to_delete_a_partition_with_fdisk to look for commands.
3. Use single letter commands to alter the partitions.

Luckily the ubuntu partition which was not showing up in the windows' disk management, showed up in the live session command line. But still I couldn't recognize the partition and kind of lost it. So I did a complete windows recovery and got the partition listed as **unallocated space** and extended by volume.
Kind of gruesome but I got back a big chunk of my storage!